# Get List of all In-App consumable purchases

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Hoping someone has some advice; currently I am storing consumable in app purchase state by using flags in

`IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings`

This works fine but whenever a phone soft reset is done the flags are reset - what is the suggested way of tracking consumable in-app purchases across phone resets / phone changes?

Is there a way of now after the fact getting the list of consumables purchased in the past?

Comment: I've not tried this, but [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.productlicenses.aspx) there should be such a possibility.

Comment: @Romasz - thanks, the IsActive flag is again reset to false as soon as you fulfil the consumable :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows Azure Database or Mobile Service or use free database service to keep user's purchase. On phone, you can not stop the deletion. You must use database or Mobile Services on a cloud.